# Install Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard fails

Tags: ios5, installation, xcode4.2

I've download Xcode 4.2 from official site. And when installation starts - it shows an error:

[image]

Not very informative.. What is the problem? where to see logs or something?

PS.I have: Mac OS 10.6.8, Xcode 4.0, ~10 GB free space. And I want just to test my app on ios5.

**UPDATED:**

```
Installer[51580]: Failed install preflight: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=102 UserInfo=0x119de62e0 "The package “OpenGLApps.pkg” is untrusted." Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2147409654 UserInfo=0x119df06b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED")
```

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/install.log` for clues ?

Comment: See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45771/xcode-4-2-install-for-snow-leopard-fails-with-an-openglapps-pkg

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try changing your system date to a date before 26 March 2012. For details, check https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45841/xcode-4-2-snow-leopard-doesnt-install

Comment: great solution ,installed fine