# What is the latest version of xcode I can use on 10.6.8?

Tags: xcode

What is the latest version of xcode I can use on 10.6.8? Is there any way to download it? I currently have the first version of xcode 4 (i.e. not even 4.2)

Can i upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's xcode 4.2, you can download it in the dev center but you won't be able to use any newer version than that on snow leopard.
[Xcode 4.2 Snow Leopard](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode#)

Comment: You just need to navigate to page 3 or 4 and you'll find it

Comment: You also have to be a member of one of Apple's paid developer programs to download Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard. Otherwise, the OP can't upgrade.

Comment: Note that you need to roll back the date on your system for the package signatures to validate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029270/install-xcode-4-2-for-snow-leopard-fails

Answer (score 2):

4.2 for snow leopard seems to not be available any longer. 3.2.6 is
http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg

Comment: That’s not true, Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard is available on the Apple Developer portal as of 7-Aug-2017.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more from this:

[What is the compatible IOS and XCODE for MAC 10.6.8?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4265893?start=0&tstart=0)